# Aligned inside cases not behaving as expected

Tags: align, cases

I wish to format a system of equations. I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
q_1 S_1^1 &+ q_2 S_2^1 &+ ... &+ q_n S_n^1 &= (1+r) S_0^1, \\
q_1 &+ q_2 &+ ... &+ q_n &= 1.
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}$$
\end{document}
```

I expect the q's and the equality sign to be below each other, but instead there is an indent in front of the q_1 and the =1 is totally on the right. How do I obtain my desired behavior?

Comment: Ott-topic: Don't use `$$` to initiate and terminate (unnumbered) display math mode in a LaTeX document. Instead, please use `\[` and `\]`. For more information on this topic, please see the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) and the associated answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX.
2. You don't want `cases`, which adds unwanted horizontal space at its right if its contents isn't a set of rows of the form `<formula>&<condition>`.
3. You don't want `aligned`, which adds space between the columns.

With `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{5}
 & q_1 S_1^1 &&+ q_2 S_2^1 &&+ \dotsb &&+ q_n S_n^1 &&= (1+r) S_0^1, \\
 &       q_1 &&+ q_2       &&+ \dotsb &&+ q_n       &&= 1.
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Sure thing!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `aligned` and `cases` machineries are all that well suited to handle the present job. I suggest you use an `array` environment instead.

[image]

The `^{}` particles in row 1 assure that the subscripts associated with `q` and `S^1` are placed at the same depth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % col. type for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ L *{4}{CL} }
q^{}_1 S_1^1 &+& q^{}_2 S_2^1 &+& \cdots &+& q^{}_n S_n^1 &=& (1+r)S_0^1 \\
q_1 &+& q_2  &+& \cdots &+& q_n &=& 1 \,.
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: FWIW, the outputs of my answer and of [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669004/5001) are *identical*.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the `q_1 S_1^1` and `q_1` *right-aligned*, because that's what your given code outputs.

I don't understand why, but the alignment of the rightmost column comes closer to what you want if you put an extra `&` before the `&=`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
q_1 S_1^1 &+ q_2 S_2^1 &+ ... &+ q_n S_n^1 &&= (1+r) S_0^1, \\
q_1 &+ q_2 &+ ... &+ q_n &&= 1.
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}$$
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that `align` treats the entries per row in groups of two or three, and also puts extra space after each triple (between the handwritten lines).

[image]

Comment: Please add all instructions needed to make your code snippet minimally compilable.